# How to save custom Workspace Tiles to a Customisation Project Package?

Tags: acumatica

I have a customisation package with custom generic inquiries and reports. These need to be accessible using standard text based menu items on a workspace, and by custom Tiles added to top of the workspace. I have added the Site Map records for each screen to the customisation package, but these only create the text-based menu items. I cannot see how or where to include custom Tiles in the customisation package.